# Concatenate libraries in a vendor.js file out of bower components using gulp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, concatenation, angular-google-maps

I've been working on a angular project using gulp to manage my sources which came so far so good. And recently I've been trying to optimize my project and then confront the libraries I use. My bower libraries were set to be installed in my "dist" folder but as you know the libraries installed using bower comes with their sources. So I've been trying to get just the necessary files and copying them on my dist/libs directory.

I must mention that I'm new to gulp.

### Gulp task to copy main js files and their sourcemaps to a new directory (it works)

The plugins used are : gulp-sourcemaps / merge-stream / bower-main

```
//Libraries
gulp.task('libs', function () {
    return merge(gulp.src(lib.minified),
        gulp.src(lib.minifiedNotFound))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/libs'));
});
```

The libraries were called as follow :

```
<!-- build:js libs/vendor.js -->
<script src="libs/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular-simple-logger.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="libs/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular-google-maps.min.js"></script>
<!-- /build -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

### Vendor.js file

And now what I aim to do is to produce only a single vendor.js file, 
up till now I've tried a lot of gulp plugins; no success. 
I'm always confronted to dependencies issues.

The task currently looks like this, it uses gulp-resolve-dependencies and the plugins mentionned earlier.

```
gulp.task('vendorJs', function () {
    return gulp.src(lib.normal)
        .pipe(resolveDependencies({
            pattern: /\* @requires [\s-]*(.*\.js)/g
        }))
        .on('error', function (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        })
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe(ngAnnotate({add: true}))
        // .pipe(gulp.src('dist/js/main.js'))
        .pipe(concat('vendor.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/libs'))
});
```

The dependencies issues breaks totally the app, and at this point I don't even know what I'm supposed to do to make it work.

Comment: Did you get an answer for this?

Comment: Nope not one that satisfied my needs. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
// Concatenate & Minify JS
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/main/modules/**/*.js') //source files (include all js files under module folder and sub folders)
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))                 //output file
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/main/js/app'))     //location of output file
        .pipe(rename('app.min.js'))             //minified file
        .pipe(uglify( {mangle: false }))        //minification step
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/main/js/app'));    //destination folder for niniifed file
});
```

I used above script to concantanate and minify js files in the application. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but nope that's not what the question is about. I already know how to concatenate my js files. What I want to do is to concatenate only the libraries and their dependancies coming added with bower. Which this way doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `webpack-stream`, and this will merge all of them ( including your `main.js` ) :

```
var webpack = require('webpack-stream'); 
var rename = require('gulp-rename');  

gulp.task('webpack', function() {
  return gulp.src('js/main.js') // the entry point
    .pipe(webpack())
    .pipe(rename('vendor.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('lib/'));
});
```